# Need help: strange JavaScript behavior... one variable gets changed when another is set

Tags: javascript

Sorry couldn't think of a better title. :)

Here goes,

I have been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure this out.

I have the following function:

```
function changeCss(elem, styles) {

   var oldstyles = styles;

   elem.css( styles )

   for(var key in styles){
       var oldstyle = input.css(key);
     oldstyles[key] = oldstyle;              //this line is the issue
       elem.data( 'oldstyle', oldstyles )                      
   }
}
```

Here is an example of how it gets called:

```
var theStyle = { border: '1px solid red'};
//elem is a jQuery object of an HTML element

changeCss(elem, thestyle);
```

The problem is that after the commented line ( line 8 ), `styles`'s value is whatever `oldstyles`'s value is.

So for example if that particular element's CSS attribute for border was not set, ie undefined, `styles`'s value will be `{ border: "" }`

How is that even possible? That is why I am delcaring `oldstyles`; I'm making a "backup" of the `styles` variable.

I have changed the 3rd line with `var oldstyles = {};` and it seems to work correctly.

But this isn't how it is supposed to be, I need to have the old styles because later I want to reset the styles - but only the ones I changed.

I can't understand why it "breaks" when `oldstyles` equals `styles`?

I hope I am giving enough code for you to understand, and also that I am expaining myself good enough. :)

If anything is unclear, please ask.

Thank you for any insight and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because oldstyles is actually just a reference to styles rather than a copy. As it appears that you are using jQuery you can use the [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to make oldstyles a copy of styles:

```
var oldstyles = {};
jQuery.extend(oldstyles, styles);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and quick response! :) I'm giving you the check since you were first.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects are passed by *reference*. That means that, in the line `var oldstyles = styles;`. you're creating a new variable that references the same value as `styles`.

In order to create a duplicate, you need to do this:

```
var oldstyles = {};
for (var style in oldstyles) {
  if (oldstyles.hasOwnProperty(style)) {
    oldstyles[style] = styles[style];
  }
}
```

In jQuery, you can just use `$.extend()`:

```
var oldstyles = $.extend({}, styles);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and responding so quickly :)